# Issue toggling a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a div that if clicked toggles another div further down the page.

This is the HTML of the div that should do the toggling:

```
<div id="ch_display_linkedin_icon" class="asw-switch-link">
<a class="link-true active" rel="true" href="#"></a>
<a class="link-false" rel="false" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

You will notice that the `link-true` class has another attribute of 
`active`. This is added by another art of jQuery if the div if clicked.

At the moment `a` with the `active` class is the active div.

What I want to do is change the value of another div further down the page called `#LinkedIn` dependent on the value of the `#ch_display_linkedin_icon`

Basically I want to say, if

```
<a class="link-true active" rel="true" href="#"></a>
```

has the class of `active` then display the `#LinkedIn` div otherwise if

```
<a class="link-false active" rel="false" href="#"></a>
```

has the `active` then hide the `#LinkedIn` div.

What I need to do is using jQuery be able to get the value of the `ch_display_linkedin_icon` and display the `#LinkedIn` div only if it has the active class.

Have started with

```
$('#ch_display_linkedin_icon').live("click", function() {
});
```

but am not sure how to get the child element of the a.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#ch_display_linkedin_icon', function() {
    $('#LinkedIn').toggle($('a.link-true.active', this).length > 0);
});
```

Ideally, replace `document` with the selector of the element that contains `#ch_display_linkedin_icon`.

If `#ch_display_linkedin_icon` is *not* being dynamically generated by JavaScript, you can simplify the code a little:

```
$('#ch_display_linkedin_icon').click(function() {
    $('#LinkedIn').toggle($('a.link-true.active', this).length > 0);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Blender. Your version does work but it sometimes works in the incorrect order. IE. Sometimes clicking the checkbox causes the toggle to 'hide' the div when it should display. I think this is because sometime the #LinkedIn div is already displayed because it was saved earlier as displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
  $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#LinkedIn').hide();
        /* This is the code to toggle the checkbox */
        $('.asw-switch-link a').live('click',function(){
            var $tag = $(this).parent();
            $('a',$tag).toggleClass('active');
            var rel = $('a.active',$tag).attr('rel');
            $tag.next('.plugin-switch-value').val(rel);
           if ($('#display_linkedin_icon').val() != 'true') {
            $('#LinkedIn').show();
           }else{
               $('#LinkedIn').hide();
           }

            return false;
        });

        $('#ch_display_linkedin_icon').click(function() {
            $('#LinkedIn').toggle($('a.link-true.active', this).length > 0);
        });
   });
```

see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lokeshparihar/26XgJ/)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response jhonraymos. The first chunk didn't work but now gets me thinking. I think the 2nd chunk may work but it has a syntax error in line 2.

Comment: The 2nd one still has a syntax error. 2nd last line. extra } I think.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am trying my best to get it to go. I appreciate your help

Comment: Just trying to work out the logic. From what I can see in Firebug. Could you do something like ( if rel="true" and has the 'active' class), then the show or hide div?

Comment: Sure, I will try and put one up on Fiddle now. Just be a minute

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17326/discussion-between-jason-and-jhonraymos)

Comment: Using your code unfortunately breaks the functionality of the jQuery fancy checkboxes